# Camunda Timer Event with Time cycle Repeatation is not Working

Tags: java, spring, timer, camunda, camunda-modeler

I am currently trying to use a timer event with a timecycle to execute a script task multiple times. I use the following code to define the timer event.

```
        <bpmn:boundaryEvent id="Event_12mc2pf" cancelActivity="false" attachedToRef="Activity_1wf3mho">
      <bpmn:timerEventDefinition id="TimerEventDefinition_0c8olxa">
        <bpmn:timeCycle xsi:type="bpmn:tFormalExpression">R4/PT30S</bpmn:timeCycle>
      </bpmn:timerEventDefinition>
    </bpmn:boundaryEvent>
  </bpmn:process>
```

After the timer event there is the script task and after the script task an end event.

When deploying and executing this process the script task is only executed once. Since [camunda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuYua.png) claims to support this feature my question is, whether I defined the event correctly.

Comment: Not answer, but rather a finding.
It might be the correct behaviour https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/doc.1111/e15176/timers_bpmpd.htm#BPMPD581

It says: When you configure a timer intermediate event as a cycle, the timer event only runs one time. It waits until the specified interval passes and then the token continues moving through the rest of the process flow.